# Resolving external resources in html head

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code below, index.html page is not getting styled in the browser as per the css and js it links to in the head of index.html. There is also a script tag before the closing body tag. I tried removing the ".." and playing around with the path for no avail.

**index.html siblings are folders:**
css, js and jquery.mobile-1.4.5

**Contents of css folder:**
index.css

**Content of js folder:**
index.js
jquery-1.11.3

**Contents of jquery.mobile-1.4.5 folder:**

[image]

Will the links in the head tag resolve correctly? if not, please suggest. Thanks

```js
$("header .ui-btn-left").on("tap", drawerToggle);
$(".contentDiv nav").on("swipeleft", drawerClose);
$("ul").children("li").on("tap", navItemHandler);
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", middleButtonGone);

function drawerToggle() {
   var left = $("nav").offset().left;
   var width = $("nav").width();
   if (left == 0) {
      $("nav").css({
         "left" : -width
      });
   } else {
      $("nav").css({
         "left" : 0
      });
   }
}

function drawerClose() {
   var left = $("nav").offset().left;
   var width = $("nav").width();
   if (left == 0) {
      $("nav").css({
         "left" : -width
      });
   }
}

function drawerOpen() {
   var left = $("nav").offset().left;
   var width = $("nav").width();
   if (left != 0) {
      $("nav").css({
         "left" : 0
      });
   } 
}

function middleButtonToggle() {
   if ($("footer ul").hasClass('ui-grid-b')) {
      $("#extra").hide();
      $("footer ul").removeClass('ui-grid-b').addClass('ui-grid-a').find("li").last().removeClass('ui-block-c').addClass("ui-block-b");
   } else {
      $("#extra").show();
      $("footer ul").removeClass('ui-grid-a').addClass('ui-grid-b').find("li").last().removeClass('ui-block-b').addClass("ui-block-c");
   }
}

function middleButtonGone() {
   if ($("footer ul").hasClass('ui-grid-b')) {
      $("#extra").hide();
      $("footer ul").removeClass('ui-grid-b').addClass('ui-grid-a').find("li").last().removeClass('ui-block-c').addClass("ui-block-b");
   }
}

function navItemHandler() {
   var selected_index = $(this).index();
   drawerClose();
}
```

```css
nav {
   width: 80%;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: white;
   left: 0;
   top: 2em;
   transition:left 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>RRR</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>
       <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
       <script src="../jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
   </head>

   <body>
      <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-bars">Menu</a>
         <h1>Activity label</h1>
         <a class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-gear">Info</a>
      </header>

      <div data-role="content" class="contentDiv">
         <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
         </form>

         <nav>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
               <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="France" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">France</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="Germany" class="ui-li-icon">Germany</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="Great Britain" class="ui-li-icon">Great Britain</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="Finland" class="ui-li-icon">Finland</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="css/images/image.png" alt="United States" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">United States</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav><!-- /side navigation -->
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <button type="submit" data-theme="c">
                     NO
                  </button>
               </li>
               <li id="extra">
                  <button type="submit" data-theme="c">
                     EXTRA
                  </button>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <button type="submit" data-theme="c">
                     YES
                  </button>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </footer><!-- footer -->
      <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

index.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your paths are wrong**

If index.html is a sibling to the resource folders, then the paths to the folders should not be "../some path", it should be "some path".

Change to the following in head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
```

Change to the following at the end of the body:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

It might be good to understand relative [path's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29), specifically in regards to a parent directory.